# Bash script to ping a IP and if the ms is over 100 print a echo msg

Tags: bash, shell, debian, sh, bin

Im new to bash scripting.

I need a script to get the ms of a ping to a IP and if the time is over 100 it will print a echo message.

For the example lets do it with the google ip 8.8.8.8

Could you please help me?

Edit:

Okay how to make it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo '>> Start ping test 2.0'

/bin/ping 8.8.8.8 | awk -F' |=' '$10=="time"'

if [$11>100]
    then
        echo "Slow response"
    else
        echo "Fast response"
fi
```

Comment: What problems did you encounter when trying to write this script yourself?

Comment: I can't catch the ms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay...  First off, you are not writing a bash script, your script is called using `#!/bin/sh`, so even if your system uses bash as its system shell, it's being run in sh compatibility mode.  So you can't use bashisms.  Write your script as I've shown below instead.

So... it seems to me that if you want your `ping` to have output that is handled by your script, then the `ping` needs to actually EXIT.  Your `if` will never get processed, because `ping` never stops running.  And besides `$11` within the awk script isn't the same as `$11` within the shell script.  So something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

while sleep 5; do
  t="$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | sed -ne '/.*time=/{;s///;s/\..*//;p;}')"
  if [ "$t" -gt 100 ]; then
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  fi
done
```

This while loop, in shell (or bash) will run ping every five seconds with only one packet sent (the `-c 1`), and parse its output using `sed`.  The `sed` script works like this:

- `/.*time=/{...}` - look for a line containing the time and run stuff in the curly braces on that line...
- `s///` - substitute the previously found expression (the time) with nothing (erasing it from the line)
- `s/\..*//` - replace everything from the first period to the end of the line with nothing (since shell math only handles integers)
- `p` - and print the remaining data from the line.

And alternate way of handling this is to parse `ping`'s output as a *stream* instead of spawning a new ping process for each test.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -i 60 8.8.8.8 | while read line; do
  case "$line" in
  *time=*ms)
    t=${line#.*=}   # strip off everything up to the last equals
    t=${t% *}       # strip off everything from the last space to the end
    if [[ (($t > 100)) ]]; then
      # do something
    else
      # do something else
    fi
    ;;
done
```

These solutions are a bit problematic in that they fail to report when connectivity goes away ENTIRELY.  But perhaps you can adapt them to handle that case too.

Note that these may not be your best solution.  If you really want a monitoring system, larger scale things like [Nagios](http://nagios.org/), [Icinga](http://icinga.org/), [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), etc, are a good way to go.

For small-scale ping monitoring like this, you might also want to look at [fping](http://fping.org/).

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple transformations you'll need to do to the `ping` output in order to get the actual number for milliseconds.

First, to make this simple, use the `-c 1` flag for `ping` to only send one packet.

The output for `ping` will look like:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=59 time=41.101 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 41.101/41.101/41.101/0.000 mss
```

Since you want the '41.101' piece, you'll need to parse out the *second to last element* of the *second line*.

To extract the second line you can use the `FNR` variable in `awk`, and to get the second to last column you can use the `NF` (number of fields) variable.

```
ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 |  awk 'FNR == 2 { print $(NF-1) }'
```

This will give you `time=41.101`, to get just the number use `cut` to extract the field after the equals sign

```
ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 |  awk 'FNR == 2 { print $(NF-1) }' | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Comment: Why run an extra pipe?  `split()` or `sub()` should be sufficient to handle what you're doing with `cut`, no?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get a trace on slow ping times and also get a mail sent to me or anyone if you want to have that.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "You must enter 1 command line arguments - The address which you want to ping against"
exit
fi

hostname=$(hostname)

while true; do

RESULT=$(ping -c 1 $1 | awk -v time="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" -Ftime= 'NF>1{if ($2+0 > 1) print $1 $2 $4 $3 $5 " "time }')

if [ "$RESULT" != "" ]; then
echo $RESULT >> pingscript.log
echo $RESULT | mail -s "pingAlert between $hostname -  $1" foo@bar.com
fi

sleep 2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I pulled together from different examples.  It prints out the date/time along with ok or FAIL if it was slower than 100ms

```
#!/bin/bash

host=$1

if [ -z $host ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` [HOST]"
    exit 1
fi

function pingTestTime()
{
    while :; do
        test2 $1
        sleep 1
    done
}

function test2()
{
    now=`date "+%a %D %r"`
    timeinms=$(ping -c 1 $1 | grep -oP 'time=\K\S+')
    status=$?
    
    timeint=${timeinms%.*}
    
    if [ ! -z "$timeint"  ]
    then
    
        if (( $timeint > 100 )); then
          extraText="FAIL (Slow)"
        else
          extraText="ok"
        fi
    else
        extraText="FAIL (Not Connected)"
    fi
    
    #echo "Status="$status
    echo $now $timeinms"ms" $extraText
}

pingTestTime $host
```